# Is there any guide how to design and bias transistor amplifiers with negative feedback?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, negative-feedback

I was reading the ARRL Handbook and came across RF transistor amplifiers with negative feedback, which seemed interesting. However, there was no information provided on how to properly bias these amplifiers. I would appreciate any insights you could offer on recommended biasing techniques and considerations. Some specific questions:

- Are there any rule-of-thumb starting points or calculations you would recommend for selecting component values to achieve proper DC biasing?
- How does the addition of negative feedback impact the bias point selection and stability?

I'm hoping to better understand the biasing principles and methods for this amplifier topology to aid my own circuit design and experiments. Please let me know if you need any additional details or clarification on my question.

[image]

Comment: Ironically, that's about the only type of amplifier (using negative feedback) that doesn't use negative feedback for DC biasing. Reason: The choke (and B) have a few ohm DC resistance and hence the average voltage at the collector remains pretty steady irrespective of the value of the feedback resistors. Maybe try simulating it and see.

Comment: You should see https://www.rfpage.com/free-tools-to-analyze-and-plot-s-parameters-file/ Appcad 4.0 from AvagoTechnologies

Comment: Or http://www.hp.woodshot.com/

Comment: BlackFox, Are you skilled at setting the DC operating point of non-RF transistor circuits? If not, start there. There's no point messing around with RF if you don't yet understand how to prioritize goals and then apply them towards a simpler system. (The way you write makes me think you are not yet there.) Assuming this were for audio, for example, would you know how to choose goals (and why) and then handle the biasing for this topology? Also, you bring up `stability` but give it no meaning. Do you mean DC biasing stability against transistor parameter vagaries and temperature? Or?